# adding wordpress to existing ZF web app - where to install?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a ZF web app up and running. Now we are planning to add blog to our web app. I am considering using WP blog because of the super tight timeline to complete blogging system. Note: I am not looking to convert my ZF app into WP app.

There isn't much about on how to integrate ZF and wordpress on google, so before I install WP I would like to make sure that I am on the right path. So here this is what I have learned so far by looking at the bit and pieces of articles I found on internet.

My ZF directory structure looks like this: (This is just the crude structure)

```
trunk /
    module /
        app /
            (contains controller, view, model)
    public /
        css
        js
    vendor / 
        ZF
```

1) Create a new directory inside ZP app (let's say www.domain.com/blog)
2) Upload and install WP under blog directory.
3) Add the following header to the all PHP pages.

```
<?php 
/* This make the magic: */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('path-to-the-file/wp-blog-header.php');
```

My question is where should I exactly create the blog folder and upload/install WP? Is it going to be under view folder? or in the public folder? Also, is there anything I need to include in root index file for routing?

This is my index.php files looks like which is located in the public folder

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

function debug( $data ) {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        $trace  = $e->getTrace();
        $desc = array_shift($trace);
        $info = $desc['file'].' on line '.$desc['line'].'';
        $infoS = basename($desc['file']).'('.$desc['line'].')';
    }
    $errTempId = 'e'.mt_rand(0,9999999999999);
    $onClick = "e=document.getElementById('".$errTempId."');if(e.style.display=='none'){e.style.display='';}else{e.style.display='none';}";
    echo '<strong style="color:#006699"><acronym style="cursor:pointer;" title="'.$info.'" onClick="'.$onClick.'"><span style="font-size:11px; font-weight:normal;">'.$infoS.' debug:</span></acronym></strong><span id="'.$errTempId.'">';
    if( is_object($data) === true or is_array($data) === true ) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre><br />';
    } else if( is_null($data) ) {
        echo '<i>NULL</i><br />';
    } else {
        echo $data.'<br />';
    }
    echo '</span>';
}

function arrayMerge( $a, $b ) {
    foreach( $b as $k => $v ) {
        $a[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $a;
}

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

htaccess file (just in case I need to modify anything over here)

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
# The following rule blocks botnets scripts
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
# The following rule maps IP address with domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^***\.**\.***\.**
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the public/ dir is the only public accessible directory in a zend app and used as a document root of the domain. 
So if you want your blog to be under domain.com/blog/ you have to put it to public/blog/

You dont have to modify any files of the zend app.